# What is the meaning of "to by"?

Tags: meaning

Gaming in my second language, I met the phrase "I have shown the crystals to by companions...". I interested what "to by" could mean? It seems to me that "I have shown the crystals to companions" should be enough.

Comment: Honestly, it looks like a typo for "to **my** companions". I can't think of any context where it would work as-is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo

Comment: We would need to see the source to understand the context.  Otherwise I assume it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with that sentence. "To by companions" does not make sense. If this was something typed by another gamer, you cannot assume that the sentence is written correctly. Even native speakers often use incorrect grammar, spelling, punctuation, etc. Especially when typing quickly, such as during an online game, typos can be very frequent and are often left uncorrected.

Without more context, I am only able to guess what the person meant. Perhaps they hit the wrong key when typing "to my companions". If the crystals are used to purchase companions, the person could have intended to write "to buy companions."

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the source to understand the context.  Otherwise I assume it's a typo.

The one exception is when recording dialogue in something like a novel and the character has a cold.  In this case it's common to write the "m" as a "b" (as well as other conventions) to imitate the sound of someone trying to speak with a stuffed nose.

> I'b sorry but I can't go outside.  I have a cold in **by dose** (my nose).